# Linq expression in C# with no argument

Tags: c#

How does the following line of code which uses Linq expression with no argument work? (it is () =>)

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => FullName);
```

The signature of RasiePropertyChanged is:

```
protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an expression that returns the FullName string.

Based on the signature you can see that it's returning a `Func<string>` which is the same as

```
private string SomeStringMethod()//string comes from the <T> being string
{
   return FullName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This lambda:

```
() => FullName
```

is equivalent to this named method:

```
private string SomeMethod()
{
    return FullName;
}
```

The empty parentheses simply mean no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda `() => FullName` will actually get converted into a private **static** method, as the above answers mentioned.

When C# code gets compiled in intermediate language, all delegates (Func is nothing more than a delegate encapsulating a method which returns some type T (in your case, a string) and takes no input parameters).

So, basically, the lambda is equivalent to:

```
private static string AMethod()
{ 
   return FullName;
}
```

Unless you are closing under some variable in code, in which case the compiler will actually generate a nested class in order to hold the reference to the variable under which you are closing.